# Spreadsheet Formula Review

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

So if I have some code in VBA or some other language I understand I could head over to Code Review and have it looked at and people might be able to educate me in way I may be able to tidy it up, point out flaws, or simply better ways of achieving the same result.  AWESOME!

If I have a spreadsheet that does some calculations for me and I have got it working with some pretty big convoluted formulas at some points, is there a place to go to have your formula based spreadsheet reviewed (ie. no code) for potential improvement?

And on top of that am I even asking this question in the right place?

Comment: Did you go on code review and check their help center? Try to see if they have an Excel tag, and read THAT?

Comment: I did go to CODE review and saw most tags were programming languages.  I will go have a second look.

Comment: 3 seconds of research gives me that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel. Look into these to see if formula review works for them or not

Comment: still going through the excel list, from what I have seen they are all VBA related.  The description of the Tag just describes what Excel is.  If you click on the learn more it tells you what excel is used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2120/91556) to [Can we review spreadsheet formulas?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2118/91556) review of spreadsheet formulas are on-topic on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Examples:

- [Averaging a set of percentages between certain important levels](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/55759/91556)
- [Time table where workers overstay past midnight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/181775/91556)